# Return rows that are max of one column in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Sample data from my table `test_table`:

```
date           symbol      value      created_time
2010-01-09     symbol1     101        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102.5      3847475500
2010-01-10     symbol2     204        3847474847
2010-01-11     symbol1     109        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol1     105        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol2     206        3847474847
```

Given the table above, I am trying to find the optimal index to put on the table (date, symbol, value and created_time should combined be unique) and the query to go along with it to return the following:

```
date           symbol      value      created_time
2010-01-09     symbol1     101        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102.5      3847475500
2010-01-10     symbol2     204        3847474847
2010-01-11     symbol1     109        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol1     105        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol2     206        3847474847
```

I am looking for date, symbol, value columns of data for each group of those three with the maximum created_time column (essentially row 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 in the example above returned).

Currently I have tried this index...

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "test_table_date_symbol_value_created_time" 
    ON "test_table" USING btree (date, symbol, value, created_time)
```

And am using this query. Not sure if it is the most effective way, it still seems pretty slow.

```
select *
  from(
    select date,
           symbol,
           value,
           created_time,
           max(created_time) over (partition by date, symbol) as max_created_time
     from "test_table"
  ) t
where symbol in ('symbol1', 'symbol2') and created_time = max_created_time
```

Comment: So you want the *latest* row for every unique date, symbol and value combination?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry I am pretty inexperienced with SQL so have been trying to read a lot and take an educated guess before asking.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the latest row for each date, symbol combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) that suit this situation:

```
select date, symbol, value, created_time
from (select *,
    rank() over (partition by date, symbol order by created_time desc) as rownum
  from test_table) x
where rownum = 1
```

For every combination of `date`, `symbol`, this query returns the `value` and `created_time` from the row with the highest (ie *last*) `created_time` of that  `date` and `symbol`.

I would suggest this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_table_idx 
  ON test_table (date, symbol, created_time, value)
```

It's a *covering* index (has all values you need for the query, obviating the need to access the actual table, and which you already had), but note that `created_time` comes *before* `value`, so data is already in its partition order, and `value` is the least important attribute, because it doesn't participate in any determination of which row to return.

Comment: Interesting that you for the query, how could I modify this to only give the latest date, symbol unique combination (so only the latest value would be given). I apologize I answered your comment above incorrectly.

Comment: @Trevor  I have removed `value` from the partition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, they make a lot of sense and seems faster at least in my testing so far than my previous attempts. Although moving created_time before value did seem to make it slower but I dont know that much about indices so perhaps its faster in the long run with some more testing (I have about 2400 symbols and about 11 million rows right now).

Comment: @Travor try executing `analyze test_table` then re-trying the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql has the very handy `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (symbol, date) *
from t
order by symbol, date, created_time desc
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

---

```
SELECT * FROM test_table tt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM test_table nx
    WHERE nx."date" = tt."date"
    AND nx.symbol = tt.symbol
    AND nx.created_time > tt.created_time
    );
```